# How to Increase background of this div horizontally

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I can not increase the background width of this div. I do not know why, I need help. [Please check the image that is on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqVvP.jpg) 

[Here is the page link http://1.edbdigital.pro/](http://1.edbdigital.pro/)

I want to lengthen the background horizontally (widght: 100%) and center the content of it

**Html**

```
<div class="symple-callout symple-clearfix  ">
        <div class="symple-callout-caption">Peça agora um orçamento para seu projeto
        </div>
        <div class="symple-callout-button">
            <a href="#" class="symple-button large blue" title="Visit Site" style="border-radius:5px" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
            <span class="symple-button-inner" style="border-radius:5px">PEDIR ORÇAMENTO</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
.symple-callout { padding: 20px 30px; background: #f1f1f1; position: relative; border-radius: 0px; width: 100%}
.symple-callout-caption { float: left; font-size: 2.6em; font-weight: 400; width: 80%; color: #555; line-height: 100%; }
.symple-callout-button { float: right;}


.symple-callout-caption { text-align: center }
.symple-callout-caption { float: none; font-size: 1.6em; font-weight: 400; width: 100%; color: #555; }
.symple-callout-button { position: inherit; right: auto; top: auto; margin: 20px auto 0; text-align: center; }

.symple-clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
```

Thanks you

Comment: It's impossible to debug the problem with just that part of the code, please include a fiddle or codepen demo as well

Comment: Do you have a link to the page itself?

Comment: backgrounds can't really extend outside of their containing block. If you want the background in that red box to spread across the entire screen, then that red box has to be the width of the screen.

Comment: also I would suggest combining your css, it looks like you have a couple classes written instead of just using one for everything

Comment: Here is the page link [http://1.edbdigital.pro/](http://1.edbdigital.pro/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a container `<div class="section mcb-section">` with a fixed width, which doesn't allow inner blocks to have a width more than 1200px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1240px)
.section_wrapper, .container {
    max-width: 1200px; //this line
}
```

You can split your container into two wrappers and insert a `<div class="symple-callout-caption">` block in there like so:

```
<div class="section mcb-section">
....
</div>

<div class="symple-callout symple-clearfix">
...
</div>

<div class="section mcb-section">
....
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Ilya Kalinin,
Your comment gave me ideas to solve the problem.
I've solved the problem. Thank you very much. :)